# update cell when column header matches a list

Tags: excel, vba

I am not the greatest at Excel vba but know enough to be dangerous.

I have Sheet1 which has records with App ID(A), status(B) and a free text field(C) we use for notes which can have many carriage returns or none.

Sheet2 contains a column for a flag name (columnA) and partial text (columnB) that needs to match to Sheet 1 notes(columnC)

I have code that creates Sheet 1 from reports and then takes the list from Sheet2,Column A and uses them as headers in Sheet 1.

I have code that I've manipulated to check if any part of the text in Column B in Sheet 2 exists in Column C in Sheet1 and if it does, mark column D in Sheet1 with a "1". The code works but I am needing to match up to the column names in Sheet 1 and update the appropriate column/flag. I've attached pictures to help show what I am needing and below is my code to date.

```
Sub Test()

Dim w1 As Worksheet
Dim w2 As Worksheet
Dim c As Range
Dim r As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set w1 = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set w2 = Worksheets("sheet2")

For Each c In w2.Range("B2", w2.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 'loop through B
    Set r = w1.Columns(3).Find(What:=c.Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not r Is Nothing Then  'found in B
        w1.Range("E" & r.Row).Value = 1 'Update value to 1 if found.
    End If
Next c

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    End Sub
```

[image: Sheet1]
[image: Sheet2]
[image: Sheet1after]
[image: Sheet1desired]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The 1st `Dictionary` object is used to store NI reason col index on Sheet1.
- The 2nd `Dictionary` object is used to store NI reason and trigger text.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic1 As Object, objDic2 As Object
    Dim rngData As Range, vKey
    Dim i As Long, sKey As String, sReason As String
    Dim arrData
    Const COL_START = 4 ' the 1st NI reason col on Sheet1
    Set objDic1 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set objDic2 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' Load data from Sheet2
    arrData = Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, 2)
        If Not objDic2.exists(sKey) Then
            objDic2(sKey) = arrData(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    ' Load data from Sheet1
    Set rngData = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    For i = 4 To UBound(arrData, 2)
        sKey = arrData(1, i)
        If Not objDic1.exists(sKey) Then
            objDic1(sKey) = i
        End If
    Next i
    ' Populate the data
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, 3)
        For Each vKey In objDic2.Keys
            If InStr(1, sKey, vKey, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                sReason = objDic2(vKey)
                If objDic1.exists(sReason) Then
                    arrData(i, objDic1(sReason)) = 1
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next i
    rngData.Value = arrData
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [InStr function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008946)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.comP/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: Hi there, I did add this and for some reason, it doesn't do anything. No errors and runs, just no values returned.

Comment: Please change `Sheet1` to `Sheets("sheet1")`,  `Sheet2` to `Sheets("sheet2")`

Comment: taller, this works perfectly! Thank you so much! May I ask 1 last question? 

I have a sheet named metrics that I will then add up all the "1"'s from Sheet 1 Columns and then paste them into the sheet "Metrics" with the column name from D to the last non-blank column as well as the count of non-blank cells

Sheet("Metrics") = 
Column A = DD: Address
Column B = sum of all 1's (ie: 67)

The column names and the amount of rows in Sheet1 will always change. Have I told you lately how awesome you are?.....

Comment: Please create a new post and share the layout of Metrics sheet. [What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions)

Answer (score 1):

What about using a formula?

If you use a formula, you might append new trigger texts to sheet 2 and your matrix on sheet gets updated automatically.

I simplified your data - but the formula itself should be clear:
[image]

Formula in `D2`

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((tblConfig[NI Reason]=D$1) * ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*" & tblConfig[Trigger Text] & "*",$C2))),"x","")
```

Comment: Thank you for this, the formula does work when in the cell but I would like to add it to my vba code and have it placed in D2 and autofill across and down to the last row while updating C2 to next row (C3), etc.

I did try to add it to my vba macro but get an error that stops at the x at the end of the codewildcard (....$C2))),"x","")

"Expected End of Statement" error that highlights right at the X, so am wondering if the new set of " there needs to be encased or a & needs to be added?

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Yes you need to add double quotes.